# How do I pull off the item duplication glitch consistently?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am attempting to speedrun the game (and maybe beat the WR some day), and my runs keep halting relatively early on because of one factor:

I'm trying to utilize the item duplication glitch that many MC speedrunners use, FearfulFerret being the most recognizable. I'm doing it on 1.10.2 (And soon, 1.11) and *have* gotten the glitch to work before... however, I'm having a lot of trouble doing it consistently. FearfulFerret does a good job of explaining how it works, but never really explains in full how it's executed.

Is there any timing or trick to successfully pulling it off, or any visual/hearable cues?

Comment: Maybe you should just do it without dup-ing items. Otherwise people will likely question the credibility of your completion time.

Comment: I'm going for any%, not glitchless. From spawn to credits. I've seen plenty of runners pull this glitch off, and it can save _tons_ of time.

Comment: Well, it's probably a lot harder to do than it used to be. A lot of glitches have been patched.

Comment: Normally it's just a repetition thing with glitches like this. The more times you do it the easier it will be for you, just keep training on it dude, you will have your WR in no time :)

Comment: Why not just use creative? It will be fast enough and same cheaty.

Comment: @AntoineHejlík You don't have the cute red hearts above your hotbar...

Comment: @rudolf then use NEI and be in survival and give items from that NEI cheat mode. #problems

Comment: @AntoineHejlík And it uses no filthy *\*shudder\** mods *\*shudder\** :)

Comment: Minecraft autosaves the world every 2 seconds. To duplicate the items, you toss them, and then hit Alt + F4 **before** the game hits the next autosave. You can never get this to be completely 100% consistant if you happen to toss items just before a save, but if you do this quickly, you can get a~90% success rate, which is acceptable enough for speedruns.(If it happens to fail, you can always start your speedrun over and try again)Edit: I don't think this works in the newer versions, and I don't think you can do it consistantly. Most minecraft speedruns use an old version (set in the launcher)

Answer (score 2):

FearfulFerret specifically uses an older version of minecraft solely because it's easy to use the dupe glitch. If you want to dupe items consistantly, you can change your minecraft version to the on FearfulFerret uses by changing your profile settings in the launcher. Even if you aren't using the most recent version of minecraft, as long as you aren't using cheats/mods, the speedrun still is valid.